# webview fragment press back to return to

Tags: android, webview, fragment, back

Hi I have an android app which a `recycleview`. When user click a `button` on a recycle `viewholder`. app will launch a `webview` (inside `fragment`). I want to handle when user click back button, `webview` will goback if there is a history, and if there is no history, the app will close the `webview` fragment and come back the `recycleview`.

I have successfull handle the back when there is a history (but webview can not come back to recycle view if there is no history

Here is my webview code

```
webView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

                public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                            webView.goBack();
                        }else {
                            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }

            });
```

Anything wrong with these code? any help is much appreciate. Thanks

Edit i use these code inside `recycleview` `adapter` class to handle button click on `ViewHolder` class

```
url.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("topStoryUrl", topStories.get(getLayoutPosition()).getUrl());

                    TopStoryWebView topStoryWebViewFragment = new TopStoryWebView();
                    topStoryWebViewFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                    if (ItemListActivity.mTwoPane) {

                        ((FragmentActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager()
                                .beginTransaction()
                                .add(R.id.item_detail_container, topStoryWebViewFragment)
                                .commit();
                    } else {
                        topStoryWebViewFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                        ((FragmentActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager()
                                .beginTransaction()
                                .add(R.id.frameLayout, topStoryWebViewFragment)
                                .commit();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: are you using the fragment in same activity where your recyclerview is ther?? or you are using seperate activity for fragment.

Comment: Hi thanks for yrs response. I have edited the question. I put button handle inside recycleView adapter  ViewHolder class

Comment: ((FragmentActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                           .add(R.id.item_detail_container, topStoryWebViewFragment)
                           // Add this transaction to the back stack (name is an optional name for this back stack state, or null).
                           .addToBackStack(null)
                           .commit();

Comment: try to replace your if condition in Listener with above and check..

Comment: work like a charm. Manythanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

addToBackStack will add your fragment to stack, and you can access this stack later

```
((FragmentActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager()
.beginTransaction()
.add(R.id.item_detail_container, topStoryWebViewFragment) 
// Add this transaction to the back stack (name is an optional name for this back stack state, or null). 
.addToBackStack(null) 
.commit();
```

Comment: thanks alot for your help. Btw how can I name the back and call the back later (for example return to specific back state instead of most current back state

Comment: sorry, i don't know about that yet, If i got any solution regarding this, i will ping u.